# Cordova InAppPurchase Implementation Auto-Renewing

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, in-app-purchase

I have InAppPurchase working in my app using this plugin:

https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase

**Requirements:**

1) 30-day free usage of the app

2) After 30-days ask user to buy any of the subscription (1, 3 or 6 months)

3) If user uninstalls app then prevent him from restarting free trail

**Constraint:**

No login or registration is required in my app, so can't check if its a returning user by reinstalling.

Does apple manage all this by itself so that user does not exploit free trail setup?

Can anyone help with the process flow to achieve these requirements?

And do I need to save transaction receipt on server side for any case?

Comment: You could offer a free trial in your subscription and require the user to subscribe immediately. Apple will ensure a given AppleID will receive only one free trial. There is no way you can limit free trials in the device alone.

Comment: Thanks, @Paulw11. So does this mean as soon as the app is opened I should show an UI to user to subscribe as per his choice of product and then apple will handle, that initially for 1-month trail user is not charged anything and after that apple will charge user as per his subscribed product?

Comment: Correct.  The user can cancel the renewal during the first month, in which case they will continue to have access until that month is up, but after that they will not be charged and will not have access.  At that point they can choose to re-subscribe but they will charged immediately

Comment: Thanks, that was really helpful :-)